# Are there any public datasets about mental health of patients containing physiological and psychological symptoms?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, dataset

I would like to segment mental illnesses with clustering using machine learning. To do so I need training dataset which contains physiological and psychological symptoms of an subject. The closest public datasets which I found are on this page https://openpsychometrics.org/_rawdata/.
However the tests were designed to fit current classification of mental illnesses like anxiety and depression, so it is not very useful for making new classification. I am searching for dataset where would bee patients symptoms prior to diagnosis and then the final diagnosis.
What I would like to find out by this data analysis is wherever the clusters match current diagnoses like anxiety or more interestingly what are the alternative classifications of psychosomatic illnesses.

Note I am not an researcher, I just want to learn data clustering on an interesting problem.

Comment: This is not really a data science question but rather a request for data. You might do better asking on [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) which is intended for that sort of request.